# Python package from parent directory not found

Tags: python, import, package

I have a python package with the following directory structure:

```
scripts
      |
       -- test.py
test2.py
MyPackage
      |
       -- __init__.py
       -- MyModule
               |
                -- __init__.py
                -- MyScript.py
```

and I'm trying to import MyPackage in test.py with

```
import MyPackage
```

and running the script with

```
python scripts/test.py
```

but I am giving the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named MyPackage
```

I understand that this can be solved by adding the parent directory to `sys.path()` but I am looking for a solution that doesn't tie me up to this file structure by adding a dependance on the path. Am I doing something non-sensible in the way I defined my package?

Comment: hmm, what about adding an —init—.py?

Comment: where? I already have one in MyPackage

Comment: in the scripts folder

Comment: Still doesn't work.